# Why is this question closed? I am asking if the English word is a good translation of koine Greek

Tags: discussion

[Among this translations of the bible, which one has the meaning of being intoxicated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568790/among-this-translations-of-the-bible-which-one-has-the-meaning-of-being-intoxic)

Note that this question asks if the following phrases all mean the same or not. I cannot understand why this is not on topic

```
too much to drink
a lot to drink
drunk freely
are drunk
have drunk freely
have well drunk
had plenty
have well drunk
```

I also ask which of the phrases is the correct translation of the word *methiosin*.

Again. Translation is on topic on this site.

Someone says that because this question is on topic in Hermeneutics it shouldn't be on this site; this reasoning doesn't make any sense. So what if this is on topic on hermeneutic.SE? I may ask the same thing over there too but I want to know what secular English language experts think. People in Hermeneutics see the Bible as some special book. I want a more natural perspective. Is "phrase A the translation of word B?" kind of thing.

Finally, there is a confusion because English word *drunk* can mean past participle of drink or inebriated. In Indonesian it can mean *mabuk* or *minum*.

So that is a very legitimate question.

One comment says that the translation is appropriate because it talks about hypothetical case and is deliberately vague and the Bible transcription is not bowdlerized. That is precisely the kind of analysis I want to avoid. I don't care if the word if the book is the Bible or not. I don't care if the word *methiosin* only shows up there. I don't care if it's a bowdlerized version or not.

I want perspective from someone that don't care about all those.

Okay I care. But I want answers from those that don't care first. That issue I can ask in Hermeneutics.

1. All I care is if all those phrases mean the same thing and if not what's the difference?
2. I care which of those phrases means inebriated by alcohol instead of just drink.
3. I care if those phrases is the best translation of *methiosin*.

I think all 3 issues are on topic on this site.

After I get those answers, I will compare the answer to the answer on Hermeneutics.

Basically I am not looking for super expert opinion. Just normal unbiased honest answer.

Answer (score 7):

The [full help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) on translation questions is worth a read, although it may not be easily accessible from the tag pop-up (I have a userscript which helps there).

> To ask a question with a good chance of a good answer, you need to indicate what the word or phrase **is intended** to mean, together with any connotation it carries (for example, is it pejorative or adulatory?) This is an essential part of any translation question. *[My emphasis]*

This is where the question fails: you're asking about the intention, but **you need to supply that.** Once the intention is known, we can help mould that into good English.

For example, the French phrase *Il pleut des cordes* literally means "It's raining ropes", but it refers to heavy rain which appears to be ropes falling from the sky. A good English translation would be "It's raining stair-rods" (which carries the same image of extended tracks of each droplet), or "It's raining cats and dogs". Once we are told what the nonsense literal translation **means,** it's possible to suggest a  couple of idiomatic English phrases.

The point of the [translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag is that this community **does not know the source language:** it's necessary for you to supply the context and general intention of the source phrase. You cannot assume a knowledge of koine* Greek and ask which meaning of *drunk* is intended for a particular Greek word.

The correct place to ask about the intended meaning is on BH.SE.

***Now,*** if all you want to do is ask

> Does English have a word that unambiguously means to be intoxicated?

then that's a reasonable question, and a probable answer is *drunk,* because  — as I commented — people cannot be imbibed, whatever Douglas Adams may have imagined†. If someone is drunk, they are intoxicated. However, there may be other words which do not have that potential ambiguity. *Intoxicated,* perhaps.

But if that's the case, we don't need all the guff about Greek. It's a couple of sentences of background at most.

---

*Note that it's *koine* in English, not *coin.*
† *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.* "It's unpleasantly like being drunk" "What's so unpleasant about being drunk?" "Just ask a glass of water."

Comment: What do you mean by intention? Should I replace the question into 3 questions?

Comment: *Intention* follows from "what the word is intended to mean." You're asking the community to supply what the word is intended to mean, and thus translate it. But **you** need to say what the word is intended to mean, and then we can help come up with an idiomatic translation for that meaning. **That** is what our translation tag is for. If you do want a translation of the Greek word, you need to ask either on BH, or possibly on [Latin.SE], who do accept questions about Greek. Be sure to read their Help pages first, and see what other similar questions there are which you can emulate.

Comment: The thing is I am not 100% sure what the intended word, methiosin, supposed to mean. I am 90% sure it means being inebriated. I think I already wrote that.

Comment: Very well. I will add link to what methiosin mean

Comment: I need one more vote to reopen. I modified the question too. Now I am just asking for the meaning. If any of the phrases mean inebriated

Comment: And **that** question can be answered by a dictionary.